# Imaplib Error being raised after a few hundred emails flagged

Tags: python, python-3.x, imaplib

I am working on running a script to mark and delete old emails that are just clogging up an old inbox for practice. When I run the script it starts marking and printing to the console as expected but after a few hundred emails it raises an error. Code is as follows:

```
# Import necessary modules.
import imaplib
import getpass
import time

# Gets users input.
username = input('Please input your Username: ') 

# Gets user's password - For most services this will need to be done through app passwords, which need to be enabled.
password = getpass.getpass() 

# Lets the user decide which folder to select emails from.
# For my use case it will be 'Inbox' first
email_folder = (input('Please select the folder you wish to have emails deleted from: ')).upper() 

# Allows the user to choose which email provider they use
email_host = input('Please input your email provider: ').strip()

# Makes a call to the email service based on users input.
email_provider_imap = f'imap.{email_host.strip()}'

# A function that will mark and delete emails, Will loop 25 times.
# I did it this way because Imaplib only allows access to 1000 emails at a time per login. 

def delete_these(user, creds, email_provider):
    x = 0
    while x < 26:
        # Creates the imap4 class with SSL 
        imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(email_provider)

        # Logs the user in 
        imap.login(user, creds)
        print('logged in!')
        
        # From user input will select the folder containing the Emails to be deleted.
        imap.select(email_folder)

        # Gets emails from the inbox and stores them as user id's, Identifies emails from before Janurary 1st 2023
        _, emails_to_delete = imap.search(None, 'BEFORE "01-JAN-2023"')
        
        # Declares emails_to_delete as a list that can be iterated over by splitting Email id's
        emails_to_delete = emails_to_delete[0].split()
        
        # This for loop iterates through and marks the emails for deletion
        for mail in emails_to_delete:
            imap.store(mail, '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
            print('Deleting emails marked for deletion: ', mail)
        print('Loop complete!')
        # Removes the Emails
        imap.expunge()

        # Closes the email
        imap.close()

        # Logs the user out to avoid raising an error from trying to use imap.search() multiple times.
        imap.logout()
        print('Logged out!')

        # Sleeps the function for a 10 seconds
        time.sleep(10)

        # Increases x by 1 so that there is no accidental infinite loop
        x += 1

# calls the function for execution
delete_these(username, password, email_provider_imap)
```

After about 600 emails are marked for deletion this error occurs.

```
Deleting emails marked for deletion:  b'9379'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Marcin Malek\Desktop\handle_emails\del_emails.py", line 49, in <module>
    delete_these(username, password, email_provider_imap)
  File "c:\Users\Marcin Malek\Desktop\handle_emails\del_emails.py", line 39, in delete_these
    imap.store(mail, '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
  File "C:\Users\Marcin Malek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\imaplib.py", line 851, in store
    typ, dat = self._simple_command('STORE', message_set, command, flags)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Marcin Malek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\imaplib.py", line 1230, in _simple_command
    return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Marcin Malek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\imaplib.py", line 1055, in _command_complete
    raise self.error('%s command error: %s %s' % (name, typ, data))
imaplib.IMAP4.error: STORE command error: BAD [b'[CLIENTBUG] STORE Bad sequence in the command']
```

I tried to make a call to an email service like Google or Yahoo mail via the `imaplib` module. I passed in credentials into the `delete_these()` function and started automating the selection and deletion of emails process. I expected it to run through the code and at the end of each loop print out messages. Once the loop finishes running I anticipated the loop to exit and the program to close.

Comment: Why do you believe `imaplib` only allows access to 1000 emails? The repetitive logging out and back in could be the actual cause of the error (the provider will throttle you if you keep on logging out and back in)

Comment: I ran the script a few times and checked the total amount of emails before I implemented this loop and it would only delete 1000 at a time before exiting the program. I do not know if this was simply coincidence or if for some reason my code only allowed 1000 emails to be stored through the imap.search function. I would think that it was the logging in and out as well, however this happening within the first loop of flagging and deletion.

Comment: Without more details, all I can offer is speculation. It's quite possible that the IMAP server you are connecting to gets upset if you delete more than 1000 messages before you expunge them; but the fix for that is probably to expunge more often, not to disconnect and reconnect after each expunge.

Comment: I'll give this a try and get back to you! Thanks for a bit of a direction with which to go!

Comment: I would suggest printing out ‘mail’ (the message set) out before every call.  Based on the error message, I expect you’re sending something weird.

Comment: I appear to have solved the problem. For some reason in the imap.search() function, it was grabbing emails from the specified date up until present instead of the other way around. This led to an error being raised when the email Id was brought up and this id did not exist, leading to the STORE command error. I changed this to using 1:1000 instead of 'BEFORE "01-JAN-2023"' and now the program is running without error.

Comment: @Max I did do that and it was still giving me a list of all the Email id's, however even though it spit them back to me it was failing inside of the list because those email Id's were generated, but did not exist when the mailbox was flagging them.

Comment: That shouldn't be an error: STORE with an invalid ID is not supposed to fail, it's supposed to silently not do anything.  (Or maybe that only applies to UIDs...).